# Stop WebView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an `WebView` in Xamarin and I need to visualize only one fix page. I set a page, but if from the webview I select a link, it change. I found the event `Navigating`, how can I stop the page before it starts loading?

**.Xaml**

```
<WebView x:Name="Browser" 
         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         Navigating="webOnNavigating" />
```

**C#**

```
void webOnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cancel the current request in `Navigating` event.

```
void webOnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Url.StartsWith("xxx"))
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, if I press on a link it changes page.

Comment: @IanGallegos Do you ensure that  `e.Cancel = true;` has been executed?

Comment: You want to push to the page not redirect to other url?

Comment: sorry, there was another error, now it run. thanks very much